# Не качает .mp4 файл через плагины pyLoad и JDownloader на FreeNAS

Tags: python, freebsd, wget, mp4

использую FreeNAS и на Jail плагин pyLoad и ранее JDownloader. Все файлы на этом плагине скачиваются с разных сайтов, но с .mp4 проблема. В обычном браузере или в каком-нибудь программе Internet Download Manager/Download Master спокойно качает эти видео даже без использования ffmpeg. Ссылки свежие и рабочие, сервера не банят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас есть какой-то код, и вы получаете какую-то ошибку. Очевидно, у вас какая-то проблема. Надеюсь, мой комментарий вам помог.

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен, JDownloader работает. для скачивания mp4 файлов, нужен загрузчик на Javascript, который отправляет GET запрос на сервер перед скачиванием.